# Rails devise 4 matched routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have hit an error with devise, on rails 4 in terms of routing. I wish to have the `/users/sign_up` route matched to `/login`. the `match :to` method yielded no results.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_scope :user do 
  get '/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```